# Manifold as a colimit?

Tags: category-theory, manifolds

An $n$-dimensional manifold is built up of pieces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ "glued together" by homeomorphisms. What I want to understand is how this "gluing" happens from a categorical point of view.

For a simple example, consider sets $A$ and $B$. Forming the union of these $A\cup B$, from a categorical point of view, we need the pushout of $A \leftarrow A\cap B \to B$, which pushout is effectively $A\sqcup (A\cap B) \sqcup B/_{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation generated by the inclusions $A \leftarrow A\cap B \to B$. This pushout has a nice meaning, it is the gluing of $A$ and $B$ along their intersection.

**My question is this**:

> How is the above example generalized in the case of a manifold. How can we use charts $\phi_i:U_i\subset M \to \phi_i(U_i)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and glue along their intersection to form $M=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$. It feels to me this should be some sort of a colimit, but I am missing the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(U_i)$ is an atlas of $M$, $M$ is the pushout of $\cup_{i,j} {\phi_i}^{-1}_{\mid \phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)}:\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)\rightarrow \cup_iU_i$, so it is a colimit where $\phi_i:U_i\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a chart.

Comment: How do the chart functions $\phi_i$ come into play?

Comment: The pushout is defined by the charts: it is the quotient of the disjoint union $\bigcup_iU_i$ by identifying $x\in U_j\cap U_j\rightarrow U_i$ with $\phi\circ {\phi_j}^{-1}(x)$. It is a pushout in the category of sets.

Comment: @TsemoAristide : Do you need some conditions on the $\phi_i$ ? Will be the quotient always Hausdorff ?

Comment: It is a manifold if the chart are homeomorphisms onto their image.

Comment: @TsemoAristide any good reference book also would be great, I'd love to draw some diagrams and ask you a few more questions but it's cumbersome here.

Comment: @TsemoAristide why do we need the charts here? Why not just take the colimit of $\coprod _{ij} U_{ij}\rightrightarrows \coprod _iU_i$? This recovers any topological space from an open cover and the data of the $U_i$ are a tiny part of the data of an atlas.