# Manifolds in category theory terms

Tags: category-theory, manifolds

Consider a collection of subsets of $M$, $M\supseteq U_i(i\in I)$, that cover it, i.e., $M=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$, and a collection of homeomorphisms $h_i : U_i \to h_i(U_i)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

> I want to view the manifold $M$, somehow as $\left.\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\right/_{\sim}$, and I want to understand what the equivalence relation should be.

Category theory tells us that 
$$
\coprod_{i\in I}U_i=\{f \ | \ f:I \to \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i, \ f(i)\in U(i) \ \forall i\in I \ \text{and }\text{supp }f=\text{finite}\}
$$
For example, if $f\in \coprod_{i\in I}U_i$ (and if we chose $n$ charts), then we could write $f$ as
$$
f=\{(1,h_1(f_1)), (2,h_2(f_2)),\dots , (n,h_n(f_n))\}
$$
where the first coordinate labels from which open set $U_i$ we have used the coordinate chart $h_i$. Note that the coordinate charts $h_i$ are necessary to attach a numerical value to the second coordinate.

What sort of equivalence relation should one introduce to $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i$ to make it a manifold? I expect something that whenever $U_i\cap U_j\neq \emptyset$ will identify in the overlap region the points of $\coprod U_i$. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Your interpretation for what $\displaystyle\bigsqcup_i U_i$ should be is wrong, you're mistaking coproducts in topological spaces (or sets) with coproducts in abelian groups, or $R$-modules for a commutative ring $R$. These have nothing to do

Comment: Care to elaborate? At least with a reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Comment: Is this not basically the same as your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503552/manifold-as-a-colimit?rq=1?